# C# - "An element with the same key was already added"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I work in ASP.NET MVC and I am blocked(surrounded) in my model with this damned error "an element with the same key was already added", I understand not at all why while I have almost the same code with different requests in other methods of my model.

And I do not think that the problem can come from the request because I have already used her(it) as before in another project.

```
public Dictionary<string,string> getDonnee()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    cn = new SqlConnection(CS_DW);
    cn.Open();

    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct(ltrim(rtrim(cpic))) as code, cpic as lib from [DW].[dbo].[PIC_PROD_S001] ", cn);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "code");

    list.Add("REEL", "REEL");
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["code"].Rows)
    {
        list.Add(row["code"].ToString(), row["lib"].ToString());
    }

    cn.Close();
    return list;
 }
```

Comment: Well have you debugged into the code at the point where it's breaking? What is the duplicate key?

Comment: Maybe `REEL` exists in the database too?

Comment: select distinct only returns distinct rows based on your column list. It's likely your data set is returning your code column with duplicate values.

Comment: Don't use `Add()`, use `TryAdd()`.

Comment: Just run under debugger, stop on exception and check current value of row["code"] - this is a duplicate.

Comment: if you want to overwrite any existing key you can do `list[row["code"].ToString()] = row["lib"].ToString()`

Comment: I do not understand why the solution of Yanga works

Comment: In my case, I was trying to add a property that was already existing in the Expando object.  Just make sure, you are not adding duplicate keys in the object. The error message is also pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can test if they key in already in your dictionary

```
if (!list.ContainsKey(row["code"].ToString())) 
{ 
    list.Add(row["code"].ToString(), row["lib"].ToString());
}
```